# How to use MaterialBetterSpinner in android

Tags: android

> 

I am using `MaterialBetterSpinner` and I want to show the country flag, country code and name of country. It correctly works in simple spinner. But when I use `MaterialBetterSpinner` it shows error in `showDropDown()` method. How can I resolve this error in android?

```
**This is my MainActivity**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    protected SparseArray<ArrayList<Country>> mCountriesMap = new SparseArray<ArrayList<Country>>();
    protected EditText inputName, inputEmail, inputPassword, inputDob, inputMobile;
    private TextInputLayout inputLayoutName, inputLayoutEmail, inputLayoutPassword, inputLayoutDob, inputLayoutmobile, inputLayoutCountry;
    private Button btnSignUp;
    private ImageView dp;
    CountryAdapter mAdapter;
    int yearc, monthc, dayc;
    ArrayList<Country> arrayList;
    static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;
    //@Bind(R.id.input_country)
    MaterialBetterSpinner spcountry;
    @Bind(R.id.country_code)
    MaterialBetterSpinner countrycode;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new VerifyPhoneFragment())
                    .commit();
        }*/
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        inputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_name);
        inputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_email);
        inputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_password);
        inputLayoutDob = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_dob);
        inputLayoutmobile = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_mobile);
        inputLayoutCountry = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_country);
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        inputDob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_dob);
        inputMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_mobile);
        dp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.calender);
        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        inputName.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputName));
        inputEmail.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputEmail));
        inputPassword.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputPassword));
        inputDob.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputDob));
        inputMobile.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputMobile));

        spcountry= (MaterialBetterSpinner) findViewById(R.id.input_country);



        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        yearc = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        monthc = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        dayc = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        showDatePickerOndp();

        String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
        countrycode.setAdapter(adapter);
        arrayList = loadData();
        mAdapter = new CountryAdapter(this,arrayList);
        spcountry.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                submitForm();
            }
        });
    }
    public void showDatePickerOndp(){
        dp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
    }

    public ArrayList<Country> loadData() {
        ArrayList<Country> data = new ArrayList<Country>(233);
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("countries.dat"), "UTF-8"));
            Country country = null;
            String line;
            int i = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                country = new Country(this, line, i);
                data.add(country);
                i++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log the exception
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }



 **This is my MaterialBetterSpinner Class** 

public class MaterialBetterSpinner extends MaterialAutoCompleteTextView implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;
    private long startClickTime;
    private boolean isPopup;

    public MaterialBetterSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public MaterialBetterSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
        setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public MaterialBetterSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
                                  Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        if (focused) {
            performFiltering("", 0);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);
            setKeyListener(null);
            dismissDropDown();
        } else {
            isPopup = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                if (clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                    if (isPopup) {
                        dismissDropDown();
                        isPopup = false;
                    } else {
                        requestFocus();

                        //showDropDown();
                        isPopup = true;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        isPopup = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
        Drawable dropdownIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_expand_more_black_18dp);
        if (dropdownIcon != null) {
            right = dropdownIcon;
            right.mutate().setAlpha(66);
        }
        super.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

}

**
```

> This is My Activity_main.xml

**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="60dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/hint_name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
      >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_dob"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_dob"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text|date"
                android:hint="@string/hint_dob" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/calender"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:cropToPadding="false"
           android:contentDescription="@string/selectdate"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:scaleType="fitXY"
           android:src="@drawable/calendar_icon" />
   </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <info.androidhive.floatinglabels.MaterialBetterSpinner
                   android:id="@+id/country_code"
                   android:layout_width="100dp"

                   android:layout_height="41dp"
                   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                   android:hint="@string/hint_mobile"
                   android:dropDownWidth="200dp"
                    />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_mobile"
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:paddingTop="27dp"
                android:inputType="text|phone"
                 />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_country"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <info.androidhive.floatinglabels.MaterialBetterSpinner
                android:id="@+id/input_country"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="@string/hint_country" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_sign_up"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Kindly post code snippet.

Comment: I attach My code snippet. Please check it